# Read a json file and run a command in Bash

Tags: awk, grep, scripting, json, mac-address

I wanna block a **mac** address which **downloaded** value is over "20480":
The json file:

```
    {
  "client_length": 3,
  "clients": {
    "ac:07:5f:77:40:e9": {
      "id": 1,
      "ip": "192.168.5.40",
      "mac": "ac:07:5f:85:40:e9",
      "added": 1576258952,
      "active": 1576264642,
      "duration": 5711,
      "token": "4d8fd3ce",
      "state": "Authenticated",
      "downloaded": 45059,
      "avg_down_speed": 63.12,
      "uploaded": 2976,
      "avg_up_speed": 4.17
    },
    "ac:e0:10:55:2d:78": {
      "id": 2,
      "ip": "192.168.5.132",
      "mac": "ac:e0:10:12:2d:75",
      "added": 1576258985,
      "active": 1576264663,
      "duration": 5678,
      "token": "35dfa494",
      "state": "Authenticated",
      "downloaded": 18663,
      "avg_down_speed": 26.3,
      "uploaded": 4986,
      "avg_up_speed": 7.03
    },
    "58:48:44:db:ba:ba": {
      "id": 3,
      "ip": "192.168.5.93",
      "mac": "58:48:22:db:ba:be",
      "added": 1576258973,
      "active": 1576264662,
      "duration": 5690,
      "token": "139fede2",
      "state": "Authenticated",
      "downloaded": 187876,
      "avg_down_speed": 264.15,
      "uploaded": 7910,
      "avg_up_speed": 11.12
    }
  }
}
```

In addition, this is the result of `ndsctl json` and it's always going to be changed. ndsctl is part of the nodogsplash package. I've installed this package on OpenWrt (BusyBox v1.28.4).

My objective:
The json above gives me some information. According to this file, I wanna block `ac:07:5f:77:40:e9` and `58:48:44:db:ba:ba` because the downloaded value of them is over that "20480".

I need a bash script to do that for me.

The commands to block **mac** addresses:
`ndsctl block ac:07:5f:77:40:e9`
`ndsctl block 58:48:44:db:ba:ba`

I've done something:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# cat test.json | grep "mac\|downloaded"
"mac":"ac:07:5f:85:40:e9",
"downloaded":45059,
"mac":"ac:e0:10:55:2d:78",
"downloaded":18663,
"mac":"58:48:44:db:ba:ba",
"downloaded":187876,
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a JSON parser for the command line called `jq` readily available for most Unices (this may have to be installed from your package system).

With it, it's easy to parse out the MAC addresses of the entries that have been downloaded more than 20480 times.

Once these are fetched, you may just pass these off one by one to `ndsctl block` using `xargs`:

```
jq -r '.clients[] | select(.downloaded > 20480).mac' file.json |
xargs -n 1 ndsctl block
```

This assumes that the JSON document is kept in `file.json`.

For the given JSON document, this would run the two commands

```
ndsctl block ac:07:5f:85:40:e9
ndsctl block 58:48:22:db:ba:be
```

Comment: Thank you. This command `jq -r '.clients[] | select(.downloaded > 20480).mac' file.json` has worked. `xargs -L 1 ndsctl block` gives me an error which **L** is a unrecognized option. `xargs: unrecognized option: L`

Comment: @M.Rostami See updated variation. What Unix are you using that has an `xargs` without `-L`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `xargs: unrecognized option: I`.

Comment: OpenWrt 18.06.5.

Comment: @M.Rostami Ah, you're (probably) using `busybox`. Use `xargs -n 1 ndsctl block` in that case (I'll update).  That `xargs` is a bit limited in what it can do.

Comment: `xargs -n 1 ndsctl block` worked. You made my day man.

Comment: Can I use a command like `jq -r '.clients[] | select(.downloaded | .uploaded > 20480).mac' file.json`? I mean, if the sum of **downloaded** and **uploaded**, so on...

Comment: @M.Rostami It would look like `jq -r '.clients[] | select(.downloaded > 20480 or .uploaded > 20480).mac' file.json` assuming you mean "if `uploaded` is greater than _or_ `uploaded` is greater than".  If you want the sum, use `jq -r '.clients[] | select(.downloaded + .uploaded > 20480).mac' file.json`.

Comment: Great. Yes, I wanted second one.